# Is there a way to click automatically on a href="locale/de"?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hy guys... looking since hours for a solution...
Is there a way to click automatically on a href="locale/de" or innerHTML "de"?
Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right show">
    <a href="locale/de" class="dropdown-item " style="text-transform: uppercase;"> de</a>
    <a href="locale/en" class="dropdown-item  active " style="text-transform: uppercase;"> en</a>
</div>


<script>
window.onload = function () {
    if (localStorage.getItem("hasCodeRunBefore") === null) {
    
        /** Way to click automatically on href="locale/de"... **/
        
        localStorage.setItem("hasCodeRunBefore", true);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why not just do `window.location.href = "locale/de"`

Comment: embarrassing ... have been sitting seriously at the laptop for hours ... thought wrong ... thank you.. CLOSED

Answer (score 0):

in DOM you can call click method that call the click event for an element

```
document.getElementById('element').click();
```

and in jQuery besides you can use click method, you can use trigger api

```
jQuery('element').click();

or

jQuery('element').trigger('click');
```